# Converting string to function name

Tags: javascript, react-native

Learning React Native. Trying to convert a string into a function name. Getting an error saying "func is not a function. func is undefined". Need some help please. The end objective is to create a view with a background color and having buttons for increasing / decreasing RGB values

```
  const [red, setRed] = useState(0);
  const [green, setGreen] = useState(0);
  const [blue, setBlue] = useState(0);

  const setColor = (color, change) => {
    // color === "red", "green", "blue"
    // change === +10, -10
    const colorCapitalized = color.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + color.slice(1);
    var stateMethod = 'set' + colorCapitalized;
    var func = window[stateMethod];

    if (color + change > 255 || color + change < 0) {
      return;
    } else {
      func(color + change);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using the `window` object (or globals in general). You certainly can't use it with local variables like your `setRed` and such.

If you really want to do it that way, put the functions on an object:

```
const setters = {
    red: setRed,
    green: setGreen,
    blue: setBlue
};
```

then use `color` to index into it:

```
const setter = setters[color];
setter(color + change);
```

or even

```
setters[color](color + change);
```

You can also do the same with the values. Then your `setColor` gets much simpler (particularly if we only do the math once and reuse the result):

```
const [red, setRed] = useState(0);
const [green, setGreen] = useState(0);
const [blue, setBlue] = useState(0);
const setters = {
    red: setRed,
    green: setGreen,
    blue: setBlue
};
const values = {
    red,
    green,
    blue
};

const setColor = (color, change) => {
  const update = values[color] + change;
  if (update >= 0 && update <= 255) {
    setters[color](update);
  }
};
```

**That said**, it seems odd to need `setColor`. You might consider looking at whether you really need that, possibly even posting a new question (**not** an update to *this* question) with the full context for why you think you need it, asking whether you can avoid `setColor`.

Comment: Hello, Mr. Crowder, I have a question in general, I use firebase storage to save images, I just take a photo URI from the picker and save it to firebase as image ".jpg"  this way right?

Comment: @OliverD - I wouldn't know. I suggest fleshing that out with more information and the code you're using, and posting it as a question.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the setters

```
// do you really need the `color` arg?
const clamped = ([value, setter]) => [value, (color, change) => {
  let w = value + change;
  if(w >= 0 && w < 255) setter(value = w);
}];

const [red, setRed] = clamped(useState(0));
const [green, setGreen] = clamped(useState(0));
const [blue, setBlue] = clamped(useState(0));
```